# Why does Windows Easy Transfer say I shouldn't use either computer while in progress?

Tags: windows-easy-transfer

I'm transferring files from my old Windows 7 laptop to a new Windows 7 laptop using Windows Easy Transfer over my home wireless network.

It's been going for 24 hours now and is making slow progress (it's got 1 day 3 hours remaining).

It says I can't use either computer during transfer but I wonder is it because it will slow it down or will it cause errors?

Answer (score 2):

Because ANYTHING you do might change things on your hard drive, things that Easy Transfer may or may not care about. This may - repeat MAY - cause errors. If you want a clean copy of your files and settings, follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It could slow the transfer down (even more) since you'll be using system resources (disks, memory, CPU, network, etc.) for your tasks as well. This may not be much of an impact though, depending on what you're doing.

You also increase the risk of you interrupting the transfer, and causing it to stop before it's done.

Additionally you may end up not transferring files you change, because it packed them already.

Otherwise, go ahead. :)